# Long-lived objects in an Apache CXF-based application

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf

I am building the server part of a client-server application, which communicate with each other using web services, implemented using Apache CXF.

In the application I want to have an object, which is created when the web application is deployed and lives until it is stopped and/or undeployed.

Let's call it `MyBackend backend`.

I also want to have different web services, like `http://myserver.com/service1` and `http://myserver.com/service2`, which

1. receive requests from client,
2. pass them to the `backend` object and
3. send the return values of `MyBackend` methods back to the client.

I plan to create following two classes, which use the same instance of `MyBackend`.

```
@Path("/service1")
public class MyWebService1 {
    private MyBackend backend = ...;

    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
  public String performOperation1(@FormParam("request") final String aRequest)
  {
    return backend.doSomething();
  }
}


@Path("/service2")
public class MyWebService2 {
    private MyBackend backend = ...;

    @POST
    @Produces("text/plain")
  public String performOperation2(@FormParam("request") final String aRequest)
  {
    return backend.doSomethingDifferent();
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. If I implement the web services like this, will the state of the `MyBackend` instance be preserved across different web-service calls (as explained above, I need this object to be alive as long as the application runs inside the app container) ?
2. Where can I create and initialize the `MyBackend` instance (taking into account that initialization can last long due to connection to the database) ?
3. Where should the shutdown procedures of the backend object be located (like cutting the connection to the database) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using Spring and dependency injection to handle this. You can define a `MyBackend` bean and then inject it into the service beans.

```
<bean id="myBackend" class="com.whatever.MyBackend"/>

<bean id="service1Bean" class="com.whatever.MyWebService1">
  <property name="backend" ref="myBackend"/>
</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="service1" address="/">
  <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="service1Bean" />
  </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend a minimal code example (preferably mavenised) for a Spring-based web service?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko You already have the code, check out http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html to see how to integrate CXF into spring.